# How to implement Icons and List view in my Collection View in Swift like in the Files app?

Tags: swift, list, uicollectionview, grid, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am creating an app to store documents and I would like to apply a toggle mode for Icons and List view. I've created the the List view with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout by using

```
let listLayoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: listLayoutConfig)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
```

to configure the Layout.
I also know how to configure the Icons layout.

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
let gridLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
```

And I've implemented a toggle function to toggle between the 2 Layouts which calls:

```
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(getLayout(), animated: true)
```

My big question is how to change the item/cell layout when I call the toggle function?
I would like to have the list view item with an image and a label in a vertical stack:
Image|Label
And in Icons view an image and a label in horizontal stack:
Image
Lavel

Does anyone know what's the easiest and most efficient solution for it?
Thank you